# Randomized questions and answers

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm making a quiz game with 3 different choices. First, I created a list with a total of 17 questions and answers. Then to make sure that the order is ramdomized every time I play the game I will `Collections.shuffle(MyList)` the whole list at the beginning.

My structure:

I'm picking a question at a randomized position in the list. But, the question is randomized between 0-2, so if I get "1", I will get the question like this `Mylist.get(1).getQuestion()`.

The choices/answers are at the position 0-2 in the list. (The first choice will be: `Mylist.get(0).getAnswer()`, the second `Mylist.get(1).getAnswer()` and the third `Mylist.get(2).getAnswer()`) By doing this, one of the answers will be correct since the index of the question is also between 0-2. And to keep the right choice in a randomized position.

However, the problem is, every time I answer a question, this question will be removed from the list. (`Mylist.remove(1)`) So, in the end, there will be less than 3 items left and I won't have 3 unique answers. My goal is to have 3 different choices with randomized order on every question, and one of them is, of course, correct. I'm new into programming and don't really know how to fix it. (Everything is in Netbeans).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post some code? It is difficult to understand the structure from your description. So the size of `MyList` is 17, and you only get first three of post-shuffle list.

Comment: What about gathering questions and anwsers in a single class, then doing a list of of this class, then shuffling the list and then transforming the list to a queue and popping elements one by one ? This way, you will always have questions and answers at the same time, and a randomized list of questions / answers

Comment: I updated the post, hope you can understand the structure.

Comment: What kind of objects do you store in `MyList` ? Can you share the code of the associated class ?

Comment: `List<Game> MyList = new ArrayList<Game>();` It contains strings and the "Game" is my constructor to get and set question/answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have 17 questions and each question has a correct answer, and you need to show each of these questions with three proposed answers, one of which is correct and other two are wrong (but these are correct answers to other questions)?

Shuffle the list only once, at the beginning of the program. Then, use a `for` loop to present the questions in order. Don't remove answered questions; the loop will ensure that each question is asked only once. Since the list is shuffled, the user will not be able to predict questions.

Then, fill in the proposed answers: put the correct answer at a random position, and fill the remaining positions with random other answers (use the `while` loop to ensure that these answers are different from the correct one and from each other).

Something like:

```
Collections.shuffle(MyList);

for(int i=0; i<MyList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(MyList.get(i).getQuestion();

    Answer[] answers=new Answer[3];
    int correct=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    answers[correct]=MyList.get(i).getAnswer();

    int j=i, k=i;

    while( j==i ){
        j = (int)(Math.random()*MyList.size());
    }
    answers[(correct+1)%3] = MyList.get(j).getAnswer();

    while( k==i || k==j ){
        k=(int)(Math.random()*MyList.size());
    }
    answers[(correct+2)%3] = MyList.get(k).getAnswer();

    System.out.println("Answers:");
    for(int t=0;t<3;t++){
        System.out.println(answers[t]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but what does `answers[(correct+2)%3]` mean?

Comment: Just don't understand the why you wrote `(correct + 2)%3`

Comment: @skyever, `%` is the [modulus operator](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm), i.e. remainder from division. `(correct+1)%3` and `(correct+2)%3` are to fill the two remaining incorrect answers. For example, if the randomly chosen position of the correct answer happens to be 1, then `(correct+1)%3 = (1+1)%3 = 2%3 = 2`, so the 2nd answer will be filled randomly; `(correct+2)%3 = (1+2)%3 = 3%3 = 0`, so the 0th answer will also be filled randomly.

Comment: @skyever, 2 is less than 3, therefore (working in integers) 2/3 is 0, and the remainder from that is 2.

Comment: Hey again! Why did you write  `int j=i, k=i;` ? Isn't is enough to go with: `int j; int k;` ? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @skyever! If I wrote `int j,k;`, then I would receive a compiler error "variables j and k might not have been initialized", because they are used in the loop condition before the random assignment is performed. I assigned `i` to both variables to ensure that the first iteration of the loop is executed. Actually I could use the "do...while" loop: `int j,k; do{ j = (int)(Math.random()*MyList.size()); } while( j==i );` In this case, it's not necessary to initialize the variables because the loop condition is checked after the loop body.